# Passing a ViewModel into view within Identity pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages, .net-framework-version

Within a controller called AccountController, I have a method MeetingLog() that gathers the info I need and it stores it within a ViewModel. I then take that ViewModel called meetingInfo and try to pass it into the view/razor page using "return View(meetingInfo)". Normally, to access the ViewModel I would have gone right into a Views folder and insert "@model ITMatching.ViewModels.MeetingLogViewModel" at the top of MeetingLog.cshtml file. Unfortunately, this razor page is located within the "identity pages" and requires a bit more work to access the ViewModel.

The problem with this specific directory "Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/MeetingLog.cshtml" is that makes using the anchor tag helper attribute (asp-controller) hard to use in the _ManageNav.cshtml file.

[Image of the identity directory the view is located in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCkrn.png)

The example I'm working with:
[code of where asp-controller is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qofSM.png)

asp-controller could have been accessed using asp-controller="Manage/Account" but it always converts the '/' into "%2F" making the page inaccessible. And only using asp-controller="Account" ignores looking into the "Areas/Identity/..." directory when that's what I need it to do.

Comment: A razor page usually has it's own actions (called handlers), that populate it's own view model. I would move your code from your controller action to a page handler.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a ViewModel into view within Identity pages or between two requests, you could use Sessions or TempData(backed by session state. After enabling the session middleware, you could store the object (need to add the session extension or TempData extension) using session and TempData, then in the Razor Page OnGet method, you could get value from the session and TempData and assign it to the View Model.

More detail information, check the following links:

[Sending objects(And Child Objects) from a Razor page to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67672496/sending-objectsand-child-objects-from-a-razor-page-to-another/67681296#67681296)

[Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

> asp-controller could have been accessed using
> asp-controller="Manage/Account" but it always converts the '/' into
> "%2F" making the page inaccessible. And only using
> asp-controller="Account" ignores looking into the "Areas/Identity/..."
> directory when that's what I need it to do.

For the Areas, if the folder structure using MVC folder structure(contains Controllers and Views), then, in the View page, you could use `asp-area`, `asp-controller` and `asp-action` attribute to generate the link:

```
 <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">/Home/About </a>
```

For the Razor page folder structure, you could use `asp-areas` and `asp-page` attribute add the hyperlink:

```
 <a asp-area="Products" asp-page="/About"> Products/About </a>
```

Besides, you could also directly use the `href` attribute:

```
 <a class="nav-link" href="/Identity/Account/Manage/Index">View Meeting Logs</a>
```

More detail information about areas, see [Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0#areas-with-razor-pages)

[Note] For the protected pages, it required the user to login first, so, it will redirect the Login page. For example: `https://localhost:44310/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FManage%2FIndex`. After login success, it will redirect to the `Manage/Index` page.